# Room: Fts4 with string primary key

Tags: android, mysql, full-text-search, android-room

I want to create an entity that (its table) synchronized with data from a server.
The objects from the server contains string id so I create a regular field (not primary key) for this id (as the Fts4 force only integer primary keys).
But now, when I update the room database with objects from the server, the database doesn't going to replace an exists objects (with the same ids that just modified).